# AVSpeechSynthesizer word stress

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` for text to speech on 2 languages. Is there any way to specify speech stress on different part of the word?

I've tried placing `'` before and after desired vowel, and also using vowels with stress marks, e.g. `ó`, `ý` - which does not seem to have any impact.

Comment: did u found the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case (language code is ru-RU), ` char helps to set word stress.