# AVSpeechSynthesizer - emphasize certain words

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Trying to add emphasis to specific words in text to speech.

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation

let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let skview = SKView(frame: bounds)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skview

var voices = [
   (volume: 0.5, rate: 0.5, text: "This is a "),
   (volume: 1.0, rate: 0.2, text: "HUGE"), 
   (volume: 0.5, rate: 0.5, text: "deal") ]

   var utterances: [AVSpeechUtterance] = []
   for voice in voices {
       let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: voice.text)
       utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
       utterance.volume = Float(voice.volume)
       utterance.rate = Float(voice.rate)
       utterance.preUtteranceDelay = 0
       utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 0
       utterances.append(utterance)
   }
   let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
   for utterance in utterances {
       synth.speak(utterance)
   }
```

I expect less of a pause between utterances. Above code should result in
"This is a .. HUGE .. Deal".

Whereas, the pauses are too long and the speech sounds disjointed (even though I have set the pre and post delays to 0).

"This is a ..... HUGE .... Deal".

Am I doing something wrong? Are there better techniques to add emphasis to speech?

This post [on word stress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736130/avspeechsynthesizer-word-stress) suggests using ` symbol. However was looking for more effect.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS Cocoa Speech Synthesizer API supports [TUNE](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW10) format i.e. encoding of text with symbols for emphasis, volume changes, rate changes and other cool things. So I am going to synthesize my text to speech using Cocoa API, save as audio file and include the audio file as a resource in my iOS project. This of course will not work if the text to be spoken is dynamically generated within the iOS app.

Here is a Cocoa Playground to record the audio with emphasis.

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer(voice:         NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceName(rawValue: "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.samantha"))
synth?.volume = 0.5;
let saveURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSString(string: "~/Desktop/SpokenText.aiff").expandingTildeInPath);
synth?.startSpeaking( "This is a [[rate -100; volm + 0.5]]HUGE[[rate +100; volm - 0.5]]  deal", to:  saveURL as URL)
```

Here is the Swift playground updated to play the saved audio file in iOS. Thanks to  response from Bill Chan over at [discussion on playing AV within playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945704/play-a-video-with-avplayer-in-swift-playground). (IMP: Import the recorded file as a resource in the playground first)

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import AVFoundation
let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let skview = SKView(frame: bounds)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skview
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SpokenText", ofType: "aiff")!
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL);
var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = bounds;
skview.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```